# VSIX with IWizard extension debug code out of sync

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to figure out how my VSIX project stopped working [VS2022].  following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2022), I was able to run and debug my VSIX project with an IWizard implementation.  Something changed, I'm not sure what. I can F5-run and everything works but the code executing is not the latest code and I'm unable to hit any breakpoints (VS says No Symbols have been loaded for this document). I can tell its not the latest code because of the debug console messages and the UI is an older version.

I've tried a number of things including

- Clean install
- Made sure I'm in debug
- Removed the extension from VS, and just tried running debug from VS
- Verified compiled output is in AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_c281014fExp\Extensions\ {myextension}
- Property settings are set

[image]

- Assets have not changed
  [image]

I did mess around adding additional install targets but I don't think this caused any issues
[image]

Any ideas how the the project can be out of sync with the code?

I could go back to the start and implement a new project but hoping someone out there can help resolve this issue.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I don't know why it works the way it does, but this definitely fixed the problem.

I removed ALL extensions from VS using the extensions manager interface.  So, all old instances are gone (but are they?)

In my VSIXProject I would do a clean solution, rebuild, run.  I verified that the latest DLL's were being output to

C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_c281014fExp\Extensions{username}\Acme Project Template\1.0\VSIProject1.dll - **VS Build output went here**

In the debugger, when my little windows form loaded, I could tell it was old code and caught the reference in the output windows that it was loading an older version of the package.

C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_c281014fExp\Extensions{username}\Multi Project Name\1.0\VSIProject1.dll **- debugger loaded this**
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_c281014fExp\Extensions{username}\Acme Project Name\1.0\VSIProject1.dll **- debugger loaded this after deleting above**
C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_c281014fExp\Extensions{username}\Acme Project Template\1.0\VSIProject1.dll - VS Build output went here

***After I deleted all the previous extensions*** in file explorer and re-ran my project, the right code executed and debugging was enabled. IDK why the older versions were picked during debugging but it's fixed. HTH someone.